# zend framework 3 ajax adjust select options

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework3

I just started working with Zend Framework 3. I'm struggling with a more advanced issue.

I have `selectlist one` with options 1 and 2

And I have `selectlist two` with options 1, 2, 3 and 4.

When option 1 is selected in `selectlist one` only option 1 and 2 have to be visible in `selectlist two`. When option 2 is selected, then option 3 and 4.

How to do that in a Zend Form?

Comment: What has your question to do with the ZendFramework? It looks more like a problem your are trying to solve within your UI, by hiding/removing/disabling select options based on another select. Use javascript to check which option has been selected and remove/disable them in the other select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with JQuery:

```
//array categorieen en rubrieken
var rubrieken = [   
    //Nog geen keuze gemaakt
    '<option value="0">Selecteer een optie</option>',
    //Categorie 1               
    '<option value="10">Rubriek 10</option><option value="20">Rubriek 20</option>',
    //Categorie 2
    '<option value="30">Rubriek 30</option><option value="40">Rubriek 40</option>'
];

$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Alleen stap 1 laten zien (als die niet al gevuld is)
     $( "#stap2" ).hide();
    //Bij keuze categorie de rubrieken vullen 
    $("#select1").change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            if(selectedValue){
                var getOptions = rubrieken[selectedValue];
                $('select#select2').html(getOptions);
                $('#select2').hide().fadeIn('slow'); 

            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "disable_inarray_validator" option so form doesnt check if value in value_options array. Also you can check post value and modify form. It depends on actual problem.